# How should I loop through a Python 2.6 dict and efficiently check another dict to see if the same key exists?

Tags: python

In Python 2.6, I have a dict of a student's coursework that I am looping through, then checking against a second dict of course requirements to see if the student has satisfied those requirements. My code is starting to get a bit ugly though, as I'm currently looping through a FOR loop of the requirement dict and checking the student's coursework dict for each listed requirement. This results in looping multiple times through the same dict since some of the loops depend on if the student is of a certain major, enrolled in one school or another, and so on. So each time I enter the loop it's to evaluate the same data on differing "IF" clauses.

So it occurs to me that there has to be a better way, right? I fear my page load time is going to grow exponentially as I add loops through the same dict(s) multiple times for the same page load (not to mention it becoming a maintenance nightmare). My hope is there is a way to do something like:

```
if dict1{key} in dict2{key}:
    if other dependent conditions are True (e.g. non_business_major, etc):
        do something, set a var to True, etc.
```

EDIT:...adding sample of dicts.

```
# -------------------------------------------
acad_hist_condensed: [{'semester_hours_passed': u'2', 'fos': u'MUS', 'grade': u'B', 'topic_number': u'0', 'ccyys': u'20072', 'compressed_hist_crse_id': u'MUS 201J0', 'crse_number': u' 201J'}, {'semester_hours_passed': u'2', 'fos': u'MUS', 'grade': u'C', 'topic_number': u'0', 'ccyys': u'20079', 'compressed_hist_crse_id': u'MUS 201K0', 'crse_number': u' 201K'},...

# -------------------------------------------
course_reqs: [{'_created_by': u'kre86', '_updated': datetime.datetime(2014, 3, 24, 8, 56, 19), 'topic_nbr': u'0', 'requirement_group': u'Prereq', 'fos': u'FIN', 'crse_nbr': u' 320F', 'program_id': 1237L, 'major_group': u'Non-Bus', 'crse_title': u'', '_updated_by': u'kre86', '_created': datetime.datetime(2014, 3, 24, 8, 56, 19), 'id': 2L}, {'_created_by': u'kre86', '_updated': datetime.datetime(2014, 3, 24, 8, 57, 2), 'topic_nbr': u'0', 'requirement_group': u'Prereq', 'fos': u'FIN', 'crse_nbr': u' 357', 'program_id': 1237L, 'major_group': u'Bus', 'crse_title': u'', '_updated_by': u'kre86', '_created': datetime.datetime(2014, 3, 24, 8, 57, 2), 'id': 3L},
```

EDIT: ...forgot to add an example of what I'm doing now. This is a fraction of the number of times I do this type of loop.

```
# -------------------------------------------
# look for non-business major recommended
if course_req['requirement_group'] == 'Recommended'\
        and course_req['major_group'] == 'Non-Bus'\
        and is_business_student is False:
    for hist in acad_hist_condensed:
        if hist['compressed_hist_crse_id'] == compressed_course_req:
            non_bus_recomm_met = True
            non_bus_recomm_crse = hist
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Please give some sort of representation of what the two `dicts` look like __and__ what you are __currently__ doing.

Comment: @sshashank124 I've added some of the detail you requested. The dict snippets are truncated. Also, they are dicts within a list. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, in simple terms, if I have understood correctly, you want to check if a given student has taken all the required courses. If you are allowed to change the data structure, you could have a list `courses_taken` for the student and `courses_required` in the subject. In this case,

```
qualifies = all(course in courses_taken for course in courses_required)
```

Set to true if all courses have been taken, to false otherwise.

Comment: Thank you...this is very helpful. If I understand correctly, I need a static **courses_taken** dict that reflects the student's coursework, then compare that to another dict that defines the needed requirements, correct? Assuming so, I suppose I could create a **courses_required** dict for all of the aforementioned situations (e.g. non-business-major, finance-major, etc) and compare to the appropriate dicts as needed, right? Is there any way to capture what courses the student took that **did** meet the reqs?  In other words, capture what reqs matched up for a given evaluation?

Comment: No, they both would be lists. If you have that information in dictionaries, you could extract them using .keys() or .values()

Comment: If the student does not qualify, you can get the list of courses taken that were required with: `[course for course in courses_taken if course in courses_required]`; or add a not to get the courses that they would need.

Comment: That appears to be a list comprehension, right? Since I'm still in Py 2.6, I suppose I can break that out to a nested **if** within a **for** loop, right?

Comment: List comprehensions are in Python since v.2.0 http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0202/ I think some things were added later (generators?), but you certanly have enough in 2.6 to work with it.

Comment: Generators were added in 2.2 and polished in 2.3, so not a problem.